# Error in changing table name into 'order'

Tags: mysql

[image]

My question is  about renaming table into 'order' as mentioned in photo.

Comment: use `orders` instead

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code and markup and such **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: If you insist on using reserved words you should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23446378)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't do this**. `ORDER` is a Reserved Keyword in MySQL.

**You should seriously consider naming it to something else, eg: `orders`, or `orderdata`**

Still, if you want to use `order` only, then you will have to use **backticks** around it, like below:

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (....
```

or (in your case):

```
RENAME TABLE ordering TO `order`
```

Check the complete list of Keywords and Reserved Keywords in MySQL here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: RENAME TABLE (table_name) TO 'order'
code is not working giving the same error

Comment: @RaminduWalgama dont use `order` as table name. Use something else.

Comment: @RaminduWalgama check the updated answer. You are using single quotes. You need to use backticks. They look like this: `